# Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) with ggmap package

Tags: r, tidyverse, ggmap

I'm encountering an issue when using the get_stamenmap function from the ggmap package in R. Specifically, I'm getting the following error message: "error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle). Could not resolve host: tile.stamen.com"

```
mapa_aysen <- get_stamenmap(bbox = bbox_aysen,maptype = "toner-background", zoom=8)
```

I have tried several troubleshooting steps, including checking my internet connection, verifying the URL and map type, updating the curl package, and configuring proxy settings. However, the problem persists.

Has anyone else experienced this error or have any insights on how to resolve it? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I have tried several troubleshooting steps, including checking my internet connection, verifying the URL and map type, updating the curl package, and configuring proxy settings. However, the problem persists.

Comment: That hostname is not found in DNS for me either, suggesting either an outage or a change that has not migrated (yet?) to the `ggmap` package. (If you look at the source [R/get_stamenmap.R](https://github.com/cran/ggmap/blob/2832fe40eb113831aa59e51dcb579d68ca1e8dee/R/get_stamenmap.R#L236), it looks as if it tries `tile.stamen.com` when using "http" but uses a different endpoint with https ... and that endpoint is also not responsive atm.)

Comment: Tiles are now hosted by Stadia (and require API key). Pull request for migration was accepted just few days ago - https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/pull/351 - so for now you should probably install from github:  `remotes::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")` . Related: https://maps.stamen.com/stadia-partnership/ , https://stadiamaps.com/stamen/ and  https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues?q=stadia

Comment: `get_stamenmap` questions during October when things started to break due to the migration  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get_stamenmap+created%3A2023-10 , though note that those were answered before  migration changes were available through github.com/dkahle/ggmap