# Problem visualizing maps with staten maps

Tags: r, ggmap

As I did multiple times, I am trying to import a map of Cyprus using the ggmap function in R:

```
library("ggmap")
library("ggsn")

leftCY =  412259.3; bottomCY = 3811795;
rightCY = 454399.3; topCY = 3837195;

RHO_map <- get_stamenmap(bbox = c(left    = leftCY, 
                                  bottom  = bottomCY, 
                                  right   = rightCY, 
                                  top     = topCY),
                                  zoom    = 10, 
                                  maptype = "terrain")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Could not resolve host: tile.stamen.com
```

I have checked my internet connection and everything is fine. I have seen in some web links [Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) with ggmap package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77418619/error-in-curlcurl-fetch-memoryurl-handle-handle-with-ggmap-package)

that Tiles are now hosted by Stadia (and require API key) and that I should install from github: remotes::install_github("dkahle/ggmap"). I have installed remotes package, run the suggested command, and rerun the command:

```
RHO_map <- get_stamenmap(bbox = c(left    = leftCY, 
                                  bottom  = bottomCY, 
                                  right   = rightCY, 
                                  top     = topCY),
                                  zoom    = 10, 
                                  maptype = "terrain")
```

But I still get the same error, and I am stuck. Is there any suggestion or alternative?

Comment: [ggmap#350](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/350) discussed the change for the stamen API, and it appears to have been resolved/fixed 5 days ago (I am not a maintainer of `ggmap`). I don't know the timeline of release to CRAN, though you can try `remotes::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")` in the interim to see if it works (and I encourage you to report success or failure on that same issue).

Comment: Note from https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/pull/351#issuecomment-1755522728 that is appears the name of the function is changing from `get_stamenmap` to `get_stadiamap`, requiring perhaps a new API key?

Comment: I have found the following link: https://docs.stadiamaps.com/guides/migrating-from-stamen-map-tiles/. Indeed, I need to register an API. I guess I will need to register and waiting for their feedback :)

Comment: once you get a new API key, if you do a `remotes::install_github` and get it to work with the new functions, I suggest you come back here and self-answer talking through the API, the `remotes::`, and all of it, demonstrating the error and the new method working. You are not the first to ask about this, and I suspect over the next few weeks/months we may see more users needing this help.

Comment: Hi r2evans. Indeed, you are right. I have created an API key, and I have run the following command "library("ggmap")

register_stadiamaps("API-KEY")
us <- c(left = 32.2, bottom = 34.5, right = 34.8, top = 35.8)
CY_map <- get_stadiamap(us, zoom = 10, maptype = "stamen_terrain") %>% ggmap()
``` and it worked

Comment: Great! Self-answer (and ***accept*** your own answer), get a little rep, and have a big impact on fellow `ggmap`-users who follow in your footprints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the guidelines of stadia website:
https://docs.stadiamaps.com/guides/migrating-from-stamen-map-tiles/

```
Step 1: Remove the existing version of ggmap from your environment.
remove.packages("ggmap")

Step 2: Install the devtools package in your R environment.
install.packages("devtools")

Step 3: Install the Stadia Maps fork of ggmap from GitHub.
devtools::install_github("stadiamaps/ggmap")
```

I have created an API key by registering to (free, check video https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/6jUSyI6x3xg) , and I have run the following command

```
library("ggmap") 
register_stadiamaps("API-KEY") 
us <- c(left = 32.2, bottom = 34.5, right = 34.8, top = 35.8) 
CY_map <- get_stadiamap(us, zoom = 10, maptype = "stamen_terrain") %>% ggmap()
```

and it worked.

Additional comment: Be aware that ggsn is not working with newest R versions, so you need to find alternatives for scalebars and north arrow (now I am facing this problem).

Answer (score 3):

Update as of 11/20/23: `ggmap` has been [updated on CRAN to version 4.0.0](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/index.html), which includes the `get_stadiamap()` function. So instead of installing the Stadia Maps fork, just install `ggmap` again, then register your API key, and you should be good to go!

```
install.packages("ggmap")
register_stadiamaps("API-KEY")
```

Comment: Hey all, Stadia Maps cofounder here! Thanks for chiming in @Angela! We've just updated our docs as well to reflect that v4.0.0 is now live on CRAN.